# Optimizing Regexp in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I have a working script:

```
Select col from table where regexp_like (col,'^noun[ |s |es ]| noun[ |s |es ]|noun[ |s |es ]$','i');
```

Can I optimize my three blocks in REGEXP to a shorter form?

```
Good:
noun abcd
nouns abcd
abcd noun abcd
abcd nounes abcd
abcd noun

Wrong:
nounse abcd
abcd anouns abcd
abcd inoun
```

Comment: If you meant to use a group `()` instead of `[]` maybe [`^ ?noun( |s |es )$`](https://regex101.com/r/tAMg27/1)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most regex engines a word boundary `\b` can be used to get the seperate words.
But in Oracle regex you need to do that differently.

```
(^|\s)noun(e?s)?(\s|$)
```

> (^|\s) : start of string or whitespace
>   (e?s)? : optional group that has 'es' or 's'
>   (\s|$) : whitespace or end of string

**Setting up test data:**

```
create table test_table (id number(8,0), col varchar2(30), matchexpected char(1));

insert into test_table (id, col, matchexpected) values (1,'noun abcd','Y');
insert into test_table (id, col, matchexpected) values (2,'nouns abcd','Y');
insert into test_table (id, col, matchexpected) values (3,'abcd NOUN abcd','Y');
insert into test_table (id, col, matchexpected) values (4,'abcd nounEs abcd','Y');
insert into test_table (id, col, matchexpected) values (5,'abcd noun','Y');

insert into test_table (id, col, matchexpected) values (6,'nounse abcd','N');
insert into test_table (id, col, matchexpected) values (7,'abcd anouns abcd','N');
insert into test_table (id, col, matchexpected) values (8,'abcd inoun','N');
```

**Example Query:**

```
select * 
from test_table
where regexp_like (col,'(^|\s)noun(e?s)?(\s|$)','i');
```

Or use `\W` (non-word character: `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`) in the regex. Instead of `\s` (whitespace). To match also strings like "abc nounes!".

```
select * 
from test_table
where regexp_like (col,'(^|\W)noun(e?s)?(\W|$)','i');
```

**Result:**
The first 5 id's.

Comment: @MarioBernatti  Just thought of something.  If you also want to match a string like "abcd noun." then the regex should be `(^|\W)noun(e?s)?(\W|$)`.  A `\W` matches a non-word character.